# Set hashmap in JobParameter in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, jobs

I am working on creating excel file from data, for that I have created job. I want to set hashmap to the jobparameter so that I can use it in MyReader class, I have created CustomJobParameter Class.

Below code you can find to get the job parameters :

- **Get Job Parameters :**

  ```
   public JobParameters createJobParam (MyRequest request) {

       final JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
           .addString("MyParam1", request.getReportGenerationJobId())
           .addString("MyParam2", request.getSessionId())
           .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
           .addParameter(
               "MyObject",
               new MyUtils.CustomJobParameter(request.getHsSlideArticles())
           )
           .toJobParameters();
       return JobParameters;
     }
  ```
- **CustomJobParameter Class written in MyUtils class:**

  ```
   public static class CustomJobParameter<T extends Serializable> extends JobParameter {

           private HashMap customParam;


           public CustomJobParameter (HashMap slideArticles) {

             super("");
             this.customParam = customParam;
           }


           public HashMap getValue () {

             return customParam;
           }
         }
  ```

But while I am setting using custom parameters, it setting blank string, not object I am passing.

How can I pass the hashmap to my reader.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for JobParameter, a JobParameter can only be String, Long, Date, and Double.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameter.html

> Domain representation of a parameter to a batch job. `Only the following types can be parameters: String, Long, Date, and Double.`
> The identifying flag is used to indicate if the parameter is to be
> used as part of the identification of a job instance.

Therefore you can not extend JobParameter and expect it to work with HashMap.

---

However there is another option, **JobParameters**:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParametersBuilder.html

You could create a `Map<String, JobParameter>` instead :

Example:

```
new JobParameters(Maps.newHashMap("yearMonth", new JobParameter("2021-07")))
```

and then use `JobParametersBuilder` `addJobParameters` in your `createJobParam` to simply add all your `Map<String, JobParameter>` records:

```
addJobParameters(JobParameters jobParameters)  //Copy job parameters into the current state.
```

So your method will look like:

```
public JobParameters createJobParam (MyRequest request) {

     final JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
         .addString("MyParam1", request.getReportGenerationJobId())
         .addString("MyParam2", request.getSessionId())
         .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
         .addParameters(mayHashMapThatHas<String,JobParameter>)
         .toJobParameters();
     
          return JobParameters;
   }
```

Comment: While I go to jobRepository.createJobExecution(excelDownload.getName(), parameters); it throw error : jparepository org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(250)